# How to start only one version of PostgreSQL database, in this case 9.1?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have installed PostgreSQL 8.4 and 9.1 on same Ubuntu machine and I want to try to run only 9.1 and 8.4 to stay off. When I run `/etc/init.d/postgresql start` it starts both. How to start only one version, in this case 9.1 ?

Ubuntu is upgraded to 12.04, bott are installed via `apt-get install` but I added to sources list for 9.1 and then update and `apt-get install`.

There is no `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.1 start`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and how did you install 9.1 ? Why not simply remove 8.4 ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have edited

Comment: What sources and what makes you think 8.4 is installed let alone running ? error message ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen When run /etc/init.d/postgresql start it writes starting 8.4 and after starting stating 9.1 and after when I run netstat -ltnp for port 5432 I got 8.4

Comment: I suggest you remove postgresql 8.4 .

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/start.conf` and change `auto` to `manual`.

Or, if you no longer wish to keep the 8.4 database, `pg_dropcluster` it, or just uninstall 8.4.

For more information see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

You can run `/etc/init.d/postgresql start 9.1` to explicitly start just 9.1.

I figured this out by looking at the startup script. In `/etc/init.d/postgresql` you'll see something like

```
# versions can be specified explicitly
if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    versions="$2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9"
else
    get_versions
fi
```

`$2` in bash means the second argument to the script, thus.

Comment: I agree, the script does seem to indicate this should be possible, but it looks like database connections to my 9.6 instanceare still interrupted when I do this:
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart 10